# Must use API request in browser URL to get access token, in postman i just get default information about the API

Tags: python, api, request, postman

As the titles says. I have this API request: https://api.bimsync.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&prompt=none&client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1

When i use it in postman i get tons of words, when i paste it in google chrome and hit henter i get the access token i wanted. Why? Is it possible to retrieve the same information in postman?

This is the bimsync API. Documentation: https://bimsync.com/developers/reference/api/v2#authentication

[Image from postman, the access token is not within the raw text output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqhtZ.png)

[When i post the API request URL in google chrome i get this site and a code in the url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRBYs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the request as CURL when you make it in the browser and paste it into Postman. Try copying the user-agent and make sure there are no cookies being sent you're not sending in the original Postman request.